# Is this Viburnum Leaf Beetle?

Tags: identification, pests, pest-control, pest-damage

I've got about 5 of these shrubs (I believe they are Viburnum latana 'Mohican') on a side of my house I nearly never get around to. Today when I was doing a walk around I noticed they were getting absolutely decimated by... *something*. When I inspected closer I found two beetles that could have been Viburnum Leaf Beetle, but I wasn't able to capture one.

Any idea if Viburnum Leaf Beetle is the culprit here? Or possibly a fungus of some kind?

Thanks in advance!

[image][image]

EDIT: I caught one of the buggers and am now almost certain this is damage from the same type of beetle. Probably happened earlier in the year and I didn't see it. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Viburnum leaf beetle is the most likely culprit although they went through my area in the spring.

A more definitive identification can be done by looking on the underside of the leaf. It's the larvae that do the damage as they eat as much as they can before something tries to eat them.
Control of the larvae can  be done by spraying a mix of 5 ml of dish soap to 1 litre of water when the larvae first appear which is usually in the spring.

Most plants will come back from this kind of damage.